# Using value from async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I have some problem using async functions in functional component in React.
I have a functional component that needs to render some number.

The function `getNumber` : for **each** id, performs an API call to retrive a number (associated with the specific id).
The function `createArray` creates an array of those numbers out of an array of ID's (`idArray`).

The problem is that the **return** of the function(component) access value `createArray() [0]` , and I get en error because the type is a promise (return don't wait for the async functions).

What is the best solution for this?

```
 const getNumber = async (id: String) => {
    const numberFromApi = await getNumberFromApi(id); //returns an object
    return numberFromApi.num; //taking the num value out of the object
  };

const createArray = async () => {
    const arrayOfNumbers= await Promise.all(
      idArray.map(id => getNumber (id))
    );
    return arrayOfNumbers;
   }


return(
       <div>{createArray()[0]} </div>)
```

Comment: It will always be a promise. You should design the view such that it can deal with the fact that initially there will be no value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

All you can really do is to read the value from your component's state, and set the state when the promise resolves:

```
const [theValue, setTheValue] = useState(0); // or some other initial value, you choose what's best for your component

const getNumber = async (id: String) => {
   const numberFromApi = await getNumberFromApi(id); //returns an object
   return numberFromApi.num; //taking the num value out of the object
};

const createArray = async () => {
    const arrayOfNumbers= await Promise.all(
      idArray.map(id => getNumber (id))
    );
    return arrayOfNumbers;
}

useEffect(async () => {
    const array = await createArray();
    setTheValue(array[0]);
}, []);

return(
   <div>{theValue} </div>
)
```

You may want to alter your component to show some sort of loading indicator while waiting for the Promise to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create some state that you can update when the promises return:

```
// your state
const [data, setData] = useState(false);

const getNumber = async (id: String) => {
    const numberFromApi = await getNumberFromApi(id); //returns an object
    return numberFromApi.num; //taking the num value out of the object
  };

const createArray = () => {
  Promise.all(
    idArray.map(id => getNumber (id))
  ).then( 
    // use setData to set whatever you want displayed
  );
}

// you render your data (or nothing if there is none)
return(<div>{data} </div>)
```